# What is the best way to manage metadata in R?

Tags: r, data-management

In analyzing data the metadata about variables is extremely important.  How do you manage this information in R?

For example, is there a way to specify a label that will be printed instead of the variable name?

What facilities are there in R for this?

Comment: I'll add that some of the need for this in other languages (think SAS and 8 character variable name limits) isn't present in R.  If my variable is Mean_Aspririn_Concentration_after_24_Hours then I can call it that.

Comment: @Paul - you must love typing ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Quick suggestions that come to mind are

1. attributes to store data along with an object (as Frank Harrell has championed for a long time)
2. the `comment()` function can do parts of this
3. the whole gamut of object-orientation to achieve different printing behaviour etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `repo` package. You can assign each variable a long name, a description, a set of tags, a remote url, dependency relations and also attach to it figures or generic external files. Find the latest stable release on CRAN (`install.packages("repo")`) or the latest development on [github](https://github.com/franapoli/repo). A quick overview [here](https://rawgit.com/franapoli/repo/gh-pages-dev/index.html). Hope it helps.